# How to send an event to another bean in spring?

Tags: java, events, spring

In spring it is possible to do this. Does anybody have code samples?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to notify a bean about something, simply call a method:

```
@Service
public class Notifier {
    @Autowired
    private Notified notified;

   public void something() {
       notified.notify(..);
   }
}
```

But event handling is usually asynchronous. In that case you will have to create a new `Thread` (or use the [executors framework](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) since Java 5), pass a reference to  / inject the target bean, and let it notify it.

And if instead you want to notify multiple beans, without knowing which exactly, then use the [event mechanism](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events) that spring provides as an implementation of the observer pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spring Integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/spring-integration-reference.html#overview) for messaging between beans in your context. Look at MessageChannel and ServiceActivator.  You can route, filter, split messages to your beans how ever you need.